# Creating method to replace "sir" with "dawg"?

Tags: java, file, printstream

I have made a program designed to run through a text document(Shakespeare's King Lear) and replace all instances of the letter s with z and "sir" with "dawg". I have the first method working, however I am having trouble figuring out what the problem is with my other method (meant to replace "sir").

Everything looks alright but it keeps saying "Out of Bounds". Any suggestions/errors in my code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class KingLear
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("new_lear.txt");
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("king_lear.txt"));
    Scanner fileScan2 = new Scanner(new File("king_lear.txt"));
    String currentLine;
    String currentLine2;

    while (fileScan2.hasNextLine())
    {
        currentLine2 = fileScan.nextLine();

        ps.println(dawg(currentLine2));
    }


    while (fileScan.hasNextLine())
    {    
        currentLine  = fileScan.nextLine();

        ps.println(zReplace(currentLine));

    }
   }
  public static String zReplace (String line)
  {
    String newLine = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    {
        char letter = line.charAt(i+1);
        if (letter == 's')
            newLine += 'z';
        else if (letter == 'S')
            newLine += 'Z';
        else 
            newLine += letter;
    }
    return newLine;
}

public static String dawg (String line)
{
    String newLine = "   ";
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
    {
        char letter = line.charAt(i);
        if (line.charAt(i) == 's' && line.charAt(i+1) == 'i' && line.charAt(i+2) == 'r')
        {
            newLine +="dawg";
        }

    }
    return newLine;
}
}
```

Comment: Change `for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)` to `for (int i = 0; i < line.length() - 2; i++)`

Answer (score 2):

No need to reinvent the wheel. Just use [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) instead of complicating things.

```
line = line.replace("sir", "dawg");
```

All the replacement logic you have so far can be rewritten as:

```
line = line.replace("s", "z").replace("S", "Z").replace("sir", "dawg");
```

Comment: 1. Read line, 2. Make replacements, 3. Write line

Answer (score 0):

When you go through each line, you go char by char. Right here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
{
    char letter = line.charAt(i);
    if (line.charAt(i) == 's' && line.charAt(i+1) == 'i' && line.charAt(i+2) == 'r')
    {
        newLine +="dawg";
    }

}
```

But if you are on the **last** char. It will read:

```
i = line.length() - 1;
char letter = line.charAt(i);
if (line.charAt(i) == 's' && line.charAt(i+1) == 'i' && line.charAt(i+2) == 'r')
{
    newLine +="dawg";
}
```

This is a problem because `line.charAt(i+2)` will be checking for char that doesn't exist. (it is in fact 2 places too far.)

To fix this change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
```

to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.length() - 2; i++)
```

Now it won't read too far. This should fix your issue. Hope this helps :)

**Edit**: This should explain your error with it just having dawgs.

To fix the error of it just printing dawg you also need to append the other letters to `newLine` like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < line.length() - 2; i++)
{
    char letter = line.charAt(i);
    if (line.charAt(i) == 's' && line.charAt(i+1) == 'i' && line.charAt(i+2) == 'r')
    {
        newLine += "dawg";
        i += 3;
    }
    else if (i == line.length() - 3){ // checks if this is the last possible dawg
        newLine += line.charAt(i);
        newLine += line.charAt(i + 1);
        newLine += line.charAt(i + 2); // adds the last 3 chars to the string
    }
    else{
        newLine += line.charAt(i); // adds text other than dawg to newLine
    }

}
```

Using this method it should work just how you want it to. However much like Robby Cornelissen said I would look into the `String.replace()` function, because it can be *very* useful and is much more readable.

Comment: Tried this and I don't get the error message anymore, but when I go to the document it just says "dawg" over and over. What else could have gone wrong...?

Comment: @ZanderMaitland If you look back to your `zReplace` function you have an `else` statement that adds text if it isn't a s or S, you need to do the same here. I've added an example.

Answer (score 0):

in your for loop you will really get `outofbounds`

```
String newLine = "";
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
{
    //in this line
    char letter = line.charAt(i+1);
    if (letter == 's')
        newLine += 'z';
    else if (letter == 'S')
        newLine += 'Z';
    else 
        newLine += letter;
}
```

change it to:

```
// minus another 1 index
for (int i = 0; i < line.length() - 1; i++)
{
    //in this line
    char letter = line.charAt(i+1);
    if (letter == 's')
        newLine += 'z';
    else if (letter == 'S')
        newLine += 'Z';
    else 
        newLine += letter;
}
```

and for your "dawg" function change it too:

```
String newLine = "   ";
    //minus 2 index
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length()-2; i++)
    {
        char letter = line.charAt(i);
        if (line.charAt(i) == 's' && line.charAt(i+1) == 'i' && line.charAt(i+2) == 'r')
        {
            newLine +="dawg";
        }

    }
```

you are getting out of bounds because you are accessing an index out of the array using those "+1 or +2" in index.

Comment: No out of bounds errors anymore, but now when I go to the document it prints "dawg" over and over. Any ideas..?

Comment: look in your if newLine is = " " and you are just appending "dawg" in it nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell waht is causing the exception. Just by looking at the code seems like this line may be causing the issue

```
if (line.charAt(i) == 's' && line.charAt(i+1) == 'i' && line.charAt(i+2) == 'r')
```

Notice for each i you are checking postions i+1 and i+2. This will result in ArrayOutOfBoundsException when `i = line.length-1` or `i = line.length-2`